# Working with Game Center GKGameCenterViewController and challenges in iOS7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, game-center, leaderboard

My app uses Game Center and I have implemented several leaderboards, and I have a fairly bug user base and everything works well. I use the default Game Center view controller to view leaderboards etc using some code like this.

```
GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Inside that GKGameCenterViewController there is a tab for Leaderboards and one for Challenges. I did not have to do anything special to get the challenges tab to show up, but it is always blank.

If a user clicks on any leaderboard and selects a user, they have the option to send a challenge, it allows them to enter a message and everything, but then nothing ever happens once they submit. The challenge is sent but the other user never receives it and the challenges tab is already blank.

What do I have to do to implement challenges? I don't want to manually send a challenge using my app if the functionality is already built into GKGameCenterViewController, I just want to use that.

I have read this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Challenges/Challenges.html but it seems to be mostly about sending a challenge outside of GKGameCenterViewController, not using the default challenge button in GKGameCenterViewController.

Can anybody help me properly implement Game Center challenges in iOS 7 using GKGameCenterViewController, or point me to some useful sample code?

EDIT: This is the app in question if anybody wants to help me test it, but I'm absolutely sure that users never receive challenges that have been sent.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/steptracker-m7-fitness-pedometer/id714439468?mt=8